# Two has_many associations to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a blog model that has many posts and some of these posts are top posts. My intention is to have something like the following.

```
class Blog
  has_many :posts
  has_many :top_posts, class_name: 'Post'
end

class Post
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

As you can see, posts and top posts are the same objects, but the collection of top posts is different from the collection of posts. Some posts are top posts too, but others not.

The problem is when I try to do `blog.top_posts`, it returns the same collection as `blog.posts`, which are all posts from that blog. I want `blog.top_posts` to return only the posts I have associated as the blog's top posts via `blog.top_post_ids << random_post`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it about a particular post that identifies it as a top post?

Comment: Posts and top posts have the same traits and attributes. I just want to select some posts of a blog and set them as top posts.

Comment: I would add a boolean `is_top` to posts table and pass additional query when declaring `has_many` relation in Blog model: `has_many :top_posts, -> { where is_top: true }, class_name: 'Post'`. [More on this.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Customizing+the+query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that , like David asked you in comment , you have particular post.

And a post could become a top_post if , by example , he has 50 likes , or 1000 views , or wathever attributes persistent in your database making a post become a top post .

If you don't have any criteria persistent on your database , you can't use active record to gets top_post. 
Anyway if you have , you should use a scope :

```
 class Blog
  has_many :posts

 end

class Post
  belongs_to :blog
  scope :top_posts, -> { where(views > 1000 ) }  #or any conditions base on your criterias
end
```

And you can get them simply :

```
    blog = Blog.first
    blog.posts.top_posts # => [top posts belonging to this blog]
```

it's an answer based on assumption ...

doc for scope : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes
s

Comment: In the end I used an approach similar to this one, using a scope from the post model, since I already had likes and reads counts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the `has_many` is it simply attaches the ID of your `Blog` object to each `Post` object so when you call `blog.posts` or `blog.top_posts` it executes a SQL query looking for `Posts WITH id=Blog.id` thus, you get the same list twice.

I would suggest you have a single `has_many posts` and then sort the list that is returned by whatever makes each post the "Top Post." Or, if you'd like to avoid sorting I'd suggest something like this:

```
class Blog
  has_many :posts

  def initialize
    @top_posts = []
  end

  def add_top_post(post)
    if self.posts.include?(post)
      @top_posts << post
    end
  end
end

class Post
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a scope? 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

```ruby
    class Blog
      has_many :posts
    end

    class Post
      belongs_to :blog
      scope :top, -> { where top_post: true }
    end

    # this gets all the top posts
    blog.posts.top
```